# Why are my actions not dispatching when they are passed to eventhandlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my first react redux project,it is supposed to perform simple increment or decrement but the actions don't dispatch when they are passed to eventhandler although they work outside them. This is the code contained in my Redux.js file

```
import React from "react";
import  { createStore } from "redux";
import "./Redux.css"
const reducer=(state,action)=>
{
    if(action.type==="INCREASE") return {count:state.count+1}
    if(action.type==="DECREASE") return {count:state.count-1}
    return state
}
const store=createStore(reducer,{count:0})
const dec=()=>store.dispatch({type:"DECREASE"}) //not working

//store.dispatch({type:"DECREASE"}) //this works
const Redux=()=>
<div>
    <button onClick={()=>{store.dispatch({type:"INCREASE"})/*not working*/}}>INC</button> {store.getState().count }  
    <button onClick={dec}>DEC</button>
</div>
export default Redux;
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe your function to a "change listener" that will be called any time an action is dispatched. In your case you need to add   `store.subscribe(Redux)` after the function `Redux`.

You can find out more about it here: https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener

Your complete code should look like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import  { createStore } from "redux";
import "./Redux.css"
const reducer=(state,action)=>
{
    if(action.type==="INCREASE") return {count:state.count+1}
    if(action.type==="DECREASE") return {count:state.count-1}
    return state
}
const store=createStore(reducer,{count:0})
const dec=()=>store.dispatch({type:"DECREASE"}) //not working

//store.dispatch({type:"DECREASE"}) //this works
const Redux=()=>
<div>
    <button onClick={()=>{store.dispatch({type:"INCREASE"})/*not working*/}}>INC</button> {store.getState().count }  
    <button onClick={dec}>DEC</button>
</div>
store.subscribe(Redux) // <= Add this line
export default Redux;
```

Comment: Tried it ,it doesn't work, i found out that this is a wrong pattern and my app should be wrapped around a provider ,then use connect which handles subscribing the store but i wonder why this doesn't work even after adding store.subscribe(Redux)

Comment: Yes that's right. Usually you wrap the entire app in a provider but is not the only way. This should work, we're missing something. Look at the codepen https://codepen.io/supermodo/pen/gOMEpOg

Comment: It works on codepen ,i have no idea why it wont on my chrome/firefox (running from vs code)

Comment: Do you get any error in the Chrome/Firefox devtools console?

Comment: Just checked again, no, i don't.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example like a github repo?